# What is the a good phone order extension?

Tags: orders, addtocart, shopping, pos

We used to be on Volusion and their phone order page was quite nice. If someone called in to place an order we could add products to a cart from the admin side, edit prices for the customer and enter products that did not actually exist in our store. For example if they wanted to place an order for a really old part we could look up the part in a catalog and then enter it in the cart for them.

What extensions out there have people used that enable them to do these things? We've tried a couple and haven't had much luck.

Comment: This is a Magento Enterprise feature to manipulate customer carts.

Comment: We're on community.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a login as customer extension and then combine that with your own non-advertised page. This non-advertised page could be a hidden category that is in default magento theme with the add to cart links.
As for payment, you could have a checkout option that only shows up if you are at a certain IP address, or if that is not flexible enough, you could have the payment option only show up if you have been to the non-advertised page. A cookie could be set to enable that.

For the customer service you want to do it sounds as if a log in as any customer module will get you half-way there.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-as-customer.html